# More concise form of "not intended for human consumption"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a more concise way of describing something as not intended for human consumption?

For example how would you make the following more concise:

> This kind of thing [medicines in animals] was a concern when horses not intended for human consumption were found in meat fairly recently.

Comment: The only concise form I can think of is the slightly shorter, "not for human comsumption". That is what seems to be used in official documents and on labels. Either that or, "not for human use"

Comment: Perhaps "animal food and medicines"

Comment: You can always just write "NO EAT"

Comment: @curiousdannii a bit Tarzan English-esque.

Comment: I could make that sentence more concise, but *not intended for human consumption* would remain unchanged.

Comment: If I found a horse in my _filet mignon_, I'd sit up and take note!

Comment: I think the notion of "intended" has to be maintained. "horses/horse meat **not fit/unfit**  for human consumption" would be the most concise, I think, but "unqualified/unapproved/not raised for human...", although not all are shorter, would work.  See http://veterinarynews.dvm360.com/humane-groups-ask-fda-declare-horse-meat-unqualified-human-consumption?rel=canonical for "unqualified " and"not/unfit .

Comment: @IconDaemon should I have said "meat from horses" rather than "horses"? :)

Comment: "..was a concern when horse (generic singular) not raised  (or   /'not farmed') for human consumption was sold as meat (/was discovered in meat products,)" If you can fit in more of @Papa Poule's technical terms so much the better.

Comment: +1 @Hugh for all of it, but especially for the generic singular

Comment: I suppose you could substitute **unapproved**.  *This kind of thing became a concern recently when unapproved horsemeat was found in the fast food industry.*

Answer (score 2):

- [Inedible](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inedible)
- [Toxic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toxic)
- [Noxious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noxious)

Sounds like what you're looking for.

In order of relevance.

Comment: I disagree.  Not intended for human consumption may or may not be any of the above but is surely must mean something more along the lines of standard safe procedures and rules used in the production the of human food were not followed.  I’m pretty sure if the item was toxic it would be so labeled.  I wouldn't use any as a plug in for "not intended ...".  Cat and dog food are not "intended" but  are consumed by the poor.  (Inedible apply - maybe not.  I've seen some very good looking cat food.  And if I were hungry enough  .... well.)

Comment: @user116032 is that food for cats and dogs, or food made out of cats and dogs? :)

Comment: Both. 9moretogo

Answer (score 1):

Adding

- Potable - specifically related to drinking water, as in

"This water is not potable." is the same as saying that this water is "not fit for human consumption".

Comment: This word (and one of its synonyms) occurred to me too, except that plenty of non-palatable food *is* fit for human consumption. All the roots of [potable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/potable) stem from: *to drink*.